# Why is capacitance inversely proportional to voltage? And not just the electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance, voltage

I understand that the capacitance should be inversely proportional to the electric field, since if the electric field is greater, the charges can leak out towards the other plate.

But why should it be inversely proportional to the voltage?

Comment: It's unclear what you are talking about. Please describe the system you are considering.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that it is a parallel plate capacitor

Comment: What do you mean by the plates "pulling charges" from each other?

Comment: @Steeven I'm referring to the phenomenon where if, say, some negative charge appears on one plate, an equal amount of positive charge appears on the other, which in reality, is actually the negative charge repelling the negative charge, so that positive charge remains, and it just 'looks' like some positive charge got 'pulled' from one plate to the other. So yes, maybe I should've mentioned, the actual case, itself

Comment: Why would more voltage make it harder for one plate to pull charges from the other plate?

Comment: @IshanDeo Good question. Maybe what I meant was, not because of the voltage, but because of the greater distance, because of which the plate won't be able to exert a greater force. So, it is understandable that the capacitance is inversely proportional to the distance.  But why is the capacitance inversely proportional to the voltage then? Maybe, I should reframe the question

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi Okay, you are basically questioning the formula $C=\frac QV$ and asking how it makes sense that $V$ is in the denominator? I think I understand your question now, and I've made an answer. If I misunderstood, then please let me know. Yes, the question is a bit confusing and would have been clearer if for instance this formula had been included.

Comment: You should edit this question to include the information you've added in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have met an often-seen issue with how to understand and interpret physical formulas and property-relationships. The key point is this: **The formula shows a *relationship* between properties, not a *dependency* between them**.

Capacitance can be found with the formula:

$$C=\frac QV$$

As you rightly point out, we here see that $C$ is smaller for larger $V$.

But, $C$ does not become smaller **because** of the larger $V$. Rather, think of it like this: If you keep $Q$ fixed, and increase $V$, then $C$ **doesn't have to** be as large as it is. If you increase the voltage and *also* keep the $C$ constant, **then you will get more charge $Q$ stored** ($Q$ will increase)!

In property relationships like these, be careful when thinking about causes. This formula shows a relationship, but it does not show which property-change that causes another property to change. It just shows how their relationship will be, after they have all adjusted to each other's new values.

We know that capacitance is a property based purely on geometry and the dielectric in-between material:

$$C=\varepsilon \varepsilon_0 \frac Ad$$

and so, since it does *not* depend on the electrical circumstances (voltages, currents, charges) in this formula, it also does *not* depend on them in the other formula. The other formula just shows the **relationship** between, not a **dependency** between them.

---

As an example, you can compare your capacitance formula with, say, the well-known Newton's 2nd law, $F=ma$:

$$C=\frac QV\qquad\qquad m=\frac Fa$$

Does your mass, your amount of kilograms, depend on your acceleration? This formula clearly shows that a larger $a$ means smaller $m$. But obviously, just because you move (accelerate), you don't suddenly weigh less. $m$ does not **depend** on $a$ - this formula just shows the *relationship* between them. If $a$ becomes larger and you keep the same force $F$, then we must change the $m$ to fit; in other words, we are talking about another, lighter object. If not, then it is impossible to keep $F$ constant while changing $a$, because we know that $m$ won't change due to a changing $a$.

Comment: So the capacitance depends on something else (distance)?

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi The capacitance depends on distance, plate area and the in-between dielectric material's influence represented by $\varepsilon$. You can see all that from the other formula I've shown.

Comment: All these properties that define capacitance are either geometry or fixed by the dielectric material. They do not (usually) vary with the system they are placed in. In other words, **they are constant**. Currents, voltages and other properties that vary do not influence them, and thus do not influence the capacitance. **It is also a constant**. Just like electric resistance is a constant. Just like mass is a constant. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can show, using Gauss's law, that the electric field strength at all points between the plates is proportional to the charge, $±Q$ on either plate. Therefore, if the plates have a fixed separation, then work needed to take a test charge from one plate to the other is proportional to $Q$. In other words the pd, $V$, between the plates is proportional to $Q$. So we have the relationship $$Q=CV$$
in which $C$ is a constant for a particular size and shape of capacitor, with a particular dielectric.

$C$ is, by definition, the capacitance of the capacitor.

So, for a given capacitor, the charge it stores is proportional to the pd that we place across it.

"But why should [capacitance] be inversely proportional to the voltage?" Whenever you talk about proportionality or inverse proportionality, you must always state what quantities are to be kept constant. In this case, since you are appealing to the equation $Q=CV$, it must be the charge. So your inverse proportionality translates as: if we want to store the same charge on a number of capacitors of different capacitance, the smaller the capacitance the larger the pd we need put across it. That makes sense, doesn't it? As Steeven so clearly explains, the interpretation is not that the pd somehow affects the capacitance, even though the *definition* of capacitance involves potential difference.